# Designing domain model issue

Tags: domain-driven-design

First of all thanks for your input on this issue. I am fairly new in Domain Driven Design and banging my head around for solution to some issues (I think they are very basic, I am surely missing something).

Let me first describe my domain a bit. I am trying to model a typical school, which can have classrooms, each classroom can have multiple section/groups and students within each classroom group.
Users are mainly school administrator and teacher. School administrator can create classroom, teacher and student whereas teacher can create only group and assign students to a group.
School has global identity, but the classroom does not have. Classroom has local identity when it is part of the School Entity. Classroom group is unique only within classroom.

School is definitely an Aggregate root with Classroom aggregate inside and is responsible for creating, deleting, updating classroom.

1. Should we create a different aggregate root for Classroom and classroom groups (which I think not right as they don't have global identities within the domain).
2. Do we create separate repository for each of them?
3. Should we handle creation/update of classroom, classroom group at the service level?
4. We need to cache the data and Event sourcing seems to be a good idea to maintain state in synch. Do you see any issue with this?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

1. I think you should create a Classroom aggregate root. You will probably list classrooms in some reports, will you?
2. Only for aggregate roots. Children of roots are fetched by parent aggregate root repository.
3. No. If you use Entity Framework, it's enough for you to add a Classroom group inside Class object List. EF should take care of the rest. Beware of deletions though!
4. If you're talking about http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/EventSourcing.html, isn't it just a way to track changes?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Do you think I should create aggregate root for classroom groups as well. I am not using EF, so it may be helpful if I have different repositories. I was thinking event sourcing as a place where I can actually handle all the changes to correctly reflect in the cached objects. Would be great if you can shed some light on this.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delay. Does classroom group have any meaning outside classroom scope?